# Why is matplotlib only displaying one element in the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the matplotlib subplots and only one entry is displayed in the legend:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Two things may help: first a minimal working example will help (btw plotly.express includes toy datasets that are helpful for this). Second (related) the complete desired behavior is not clear.

Comment: As far as I can see from the code, this is matplotlib, not plotly. To display everything in the legend, I think you can extract the data by item in the legend and graph it.